# What is the correct way to add headers (user-agents) when scraping with urllib & Python 3?

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to add a user agent to the scrape I'm doing with urllib and BeautifulSoup in Python 3. Here's my code

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from random import choice
from time import sleep
import os

user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
    'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19'
]

allUrlData = ['www.bbc.co.uk/news','http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world']
r = range(2,4)

for url in allUrlData:
    sleep(choice(r))
    version = choice(user_agents)
    headers = {'User-Agent': version}
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
    htmlText = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(htmlText, 'lxml')
```

I'm kind of confused if when I pass the `req` object to the `urlopen()` method will it still have the user agent included.

Will this code work properly and pass the user agent?

Do I not need to use `Request.add_header(key, val)` to get this to work properly?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello, user, you could try it on a website such as http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/ and since you import beautiful soup you can just `soup.find('div',{'class':'info-box user-agent'}).next_sibling` for the value I think.... and you could use the `import requests` module instead of `urllib`. Just Google around...

Answer (score -1):

You typically use BeautifulSoup with Requests. And then specify the headers as a kwarg of requests:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random

user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
    'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
    'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.5; Linux) KHTML/3.5.5 (like Gecko) (Kubuntu)',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.142 Safari/535.19',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19'
]

allUrlData = ['www.bbc.co.uk/news','http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world']

for url in allUrlData:
    version = random.choice(user_agents)
    headers = { 'headers': {'User-Agent': version} }
    source = requests.get(url, **headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    print(soup.prettify())
```

Note definitely ensure you specify the user agent. Browsers already can detect automation when User-Agent is completely missing.

Comment: While a correct alternative solution, the question itself was about adding headers to the urllib request. You don't need to use beautifulsoup with any specific http client

Comment: @OneCricketeer right, when I answered another question correctly today, someone responded saying the other answer is better even though my answer was correct because the other answer showed another way to do it which the OP didn’t actually ask for. Now I offer a better way to do it and then I get the inverse response. You can’t have it both ways.